# SklearnClassifier object has no attribute _vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, pickle

I got a new laptop and installed the latest versions of NLTK and SciKit-Learn. I was using an old script for sentiment analysis that loaded an old pickle I created from earlier this year and I received the error below. It seems that the SciKitClassifier wrapper from NLTK now has the attribute _vectorizer where it didn't have one before.

```
  File "c:\users\yoprado\pycharmprojects\gnip_sentiment\gnip_sentiment\main.py", line 64, in mongoaddsentiment
    MongoSentiment(mongo_server, mongo_port, dbname, colname, pickle_file)
  File "c:\users\yoprado\pycharmprojects\gnip_sentiment\gnip_sentiment\MongoSentiment.py", line 61, in MongoSentiment
    senti = classifier_eng.classify(get_features(cleanedBody.split()))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\classify\api.py", line 54, in classify
    return self.classify_many([featureset])[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 84, in classify_many
    X = self._vectorizer.transform(featuresets)
AttributeError: 'SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute '_vectorizer'
```

I used the same script that created the classifier pickle from before and the new pickle seems to work just fine. It seems something in the code was modified through a recent update. Is there any way to convert the current pickle into the new format?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [type of problem is a known issue](https://github.com/ilastik/ilastik/issues/793) with `sklearn`. I have had the same general issue depickling trained sklearn models after updating to the latest version of the package. For whatever reason there is often not enough consistency between versions such that you can reliably depickle a trained model from a prior version. When you originally pickled the trained classifier it serialized a call to a function under the hood that is itself not serialized.  So when you depickle it deserializes the call but makes the call to the new version of that function which no longer takes the same arguments or has the same attributes (in your case `_vectorizer`). You have two options: (1) retrain the model with the new version or (2) install the prior version you were using rather than the most up to date version of sklearn.

Comment: I knew it was a version compatibility, thanks for shining the light on this!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use `dill` instead of `pickle` to serialize the `sklearn` model, then you should be able to recover your classifier even if there was a version change.  If you use `pickle`, serialization of class instances only saves some relevant state, but then references the class definition… so if the definition changes, you are out of luck for old pickles.  By default, `dill` pickles the class definition along with the class instance… and thus even if the class definition changes, you can unpickle your saved instance -- and hopefully extract what you need from the old class instance.  You could, for example, transfer the state from the old classifier object to a new classifier object, and move on with life with a shiny new object.  The only caveat is that you have to plan ahead and use `dill` for serialization in the first place -- if you don't, you are out of luck.